# How to return *uint8_t (array) from function of external c file to main.c

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, return-type

I want to find a error free way of  returning an `uint8_t *hex` pointer from function .I have 3 file **main.c**, **function.c** , **header.h**.

**main.c**:

```
 uint8_t *hex;
 my_ftn(a,b,c,d,&hex);
```

**function.h**

```
void my_ftn(int a,int b,int c,int d,uint8_t *hex);
```

**function.c**

```
void my_ftn(int a,int b,int c,int d,uint8_t *hex){
   ...
   ...
   a=64;
   hex=malloc(a);  //let a= 64;
   for(i=0;i<a;i++)
     hex[i]= some values;
}
```

I want to return values `hex[i] ,(i=0 to a)` to main.c.

**Note:** return type of my_ftn(function) must be void.

Comment: There are two possible solutions. Which one to pick depends on if you can change the type of the argument `hex` or not?

Comment: @superstack Show how hex is defined in main.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the variable `hex` is declared in main like

```
uint8_t *hex = NULL;
```

then declare the function the following way

```
void my_ftn(int a,int b,int c,int d,uint8_t **hex){
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ...
   ...
   a=64;
   *hex=malloc(a);  //let a= 64;
   for(i=0;i<a;i++)
     ( *hex )[i]= some values;
}
```

that is pass the pointer by reference.

And call it as you already wrote

```
my_ftn(a,b,c,d,&hex);
```